# make a title for a poster

Tags: line-breaking, a0poster

It will be very helpful if someone kindly help me fixing the title of the code below:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings}
\definecolor{pms286}{RGB}{4,52,177}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=pms286!80, fill=blue!20, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners=30pt, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=30pt,color=blue!20]
\def\Title#1{\noindent{\VeryHuge\color{pms286} #1}}


%\begin{document}
\newcommand{\displaytitle}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
      \begin{minipage}{0.93\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
      \multirow {3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{some logo}}
      & \baselineskip=3\baselineskip\Title{#1}\\\\
      & \Huge\color{pms286!90}{#2} \\\\
      & \LARGE\color{pms286!80}{#3}\\
    \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\displaytitle{A very very very very very very \\very very very very very very very very very very
long title. }{Author}{University}
\end{document}
```

NB: the logo image is missing, so, compilation will give a error. But thats not the problem here.

My problem is, with this displaytitle setting, Title is only for one line. If the title is really lengthy (two line), it can not be broken. A `\' linebreak erases the format(as shown in the picture).

Kindly help.[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [`tikzposter`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter)? It's great for creatihng posters. Just google around a bit and you'll find lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to define a `newcolumntype` from array package for text wrapping. Here two column types were defined, requiring #1 width argument. `P` is for paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top while `C` is for paragraph column with text vertically aligned in the middle. Also, `multirow` package is required which was not loaded in the OP.

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{array,tikz,multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings}

\definecolor{pms286}{RGB}{4,52,177}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=pms286!80, fill=blue!20, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners=30pt, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=30pt,color=blue!20]
\def\Title#1{\noindent{\VeryHuge\color{pms286} #1}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%\begin{document}
\newcommand{\displaytitle}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
      \begin{minipage}{0.93\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{l C{0.8\textwidth}}
      \multirow {3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.125\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
       &\baselineskip=3\baselineskip\Title{#1}\\\\
       &\Huge\color{pms286!90}{#2} \\\\
       &\LARGE\color{pms286!80}{#3}\\
      \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\displaytitle{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}
{Author}
{University}

\end{document}
```